# Capturing multiple options from a drop-down list

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am trying to capture multiple options from a dropdown list and send it through mail.
I have tried the following code.

HTML:

```
<select name="thelist[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
<option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
if( is_array($thelist))
    {
        while (list ($thelist) = each ($thelist)) 
            {
                echo "$thelist <br>";
            }
    }
    else{echo "not working";}
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: What problems are you having? I think the only problem with the code you wrote is $thelist is the same variable as the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$thelist = $_POST['thelist'];
if(is_array($thelist)){
    foreach($thelist as $item){
        echo $item.'<br>';
    }
}else{
    echo 'thelist is not an array';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `thelist[]` to `thelist`, because you are naming differently and catching with different name, do this:

```
<select name="thelist" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
<option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

and as Samuel says:

```
$thelist = $_POST['thelist'];
if(is_array($thelist)){
  foreach($thelist as $item){
    echo $item.'<br>';
  }
}else{
  echo 'thelist is not an array';
}
```

Comment: worked for me, but i needed to include the [] around the 'thelist' at the beginning